# How do you use a dictionary object to compare keys of a given array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, dictionary, object

I am doing a code challenge where I want to find the 'highest value' word in a string of words. I have  assigned the 'a-z' characters as keys and the numbers '1-26' as values in my object. I'm wondering if there is a way to compare the letters in the words of the given string to my dictionary object and start adding up values of the letters to find the 'highest value' word. Here's my dictionary object:

```js
let testStr = 'man i need a taxi up to ubud'
testStr.split(' ')
const values = [...Array(27).keys()]
values.shift()
const keys = String.fromCharCode(...[...Array('z'.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1).keys()]
  .map(i => i + 'a'.charCodeAt(0)))
const merged = [...keys].reduce((obj, key, index) => ({ ...obj,
  [key]: values[index]
}), {})
console.log(JSON.stringify(merged) + '\n' + testStr)
```

Comment: Can you give us some examples? Some words with their "values".

Comment: Also are the characters given a value based on their alphabetical order? Meaning `a` is 1 and `b` is 2 ... And what about other characters like digits and spaces ...?

Comment: You may want to change your `console.log` there to `console.log(JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2) + '\n' + testStr)`, to make it more readable.

Comment: Line 2 of your code doesn't do anything: strings are immutable.

Comment: It seems like you've already made the object with the necessary letters as keys, you just need to iterate through your string's characters and add up the corresponding values of their letters. A simple `for` loop would suffice, but a `reduce` would work as well.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, an unrelated solution: `testStr.split(" ").map(e => [e, e.split("").reduce((p, c) => p + c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96, 0)]).reduce((p, c) => p[1] > c[1] ? p : c);` (would need to add `[0]` at the end, to get just the word)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `reduce` to get the value of each word. You can also store the index of the word alongside the value, and then sort the values highest to lowest and then directly access the highest value with [0] and the word by the index [1].

```js
let testStr = 'man i need a taxi up to ubud'

const values = [...Array(27).keys()]
values.shift()

const keys = String.fromCharCode(...[...Array('z'.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1).keys()]
    .map(i => i + 'a'.charCodeAt(0)))
const merged = [...keys].reduce((obj, key, index) => ({ ...obj, [key]: values[index] }), {})

console.log(
  testStr.split(' ')
    .map(w => [w.split('').reduce((a, l) => (a += merged[l] || 0), 0), w])
    .sort(([a], [b]) => b - a)[0][1]
)
```

You could then turn this into a util function:

```js
const values = [...Array(27).keys()]
values.shift()

const map = [...String.fromCharCode(...[...Array('z'.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1).keys()]
  .map(i => i + 'a'.charCodeAt(0)))].reduce((obj, key, index) => ({ ...obj, [key]: values[index]}), {})

const getHighest = s => (
  s.toLowerCase()
    .split(' ')
    .map((w, i) => [w.split('').reduce((a, l) => (a += map[l] || 0), 0), w])
    .sort(([a], [b]) => b - a)[0][1]
)


console.log(getHighest('man i need a taxi up to ubud'))
console.log(getHighest('This is a test'))
```

It is easier and shorter to write, however, when getting the value during the loop, rather than in a map beforehand:

```js
const getHighest = s => (
  s.toLowerCase()
    .split(' ')
    .map((w, i) => [w.split('').reduce((a, l) => (a += l.charCodeAt() || 0), 0), w])
    .sort(([a], [b]) => b - a)[0][1]
)


console.log(getHighest('man i need a taxi up to ubud'))
console.log(getHighest('This is a test'))
```

Comment: I am not sure about proposing the util function as is since computing the mapping is quite inefficient. probably ```const getHighest = (//buildthemap, return s=>{})()``` would be better

Comment: @user753642 That's definitely better, but a user shouldn't have to provide the map. If it was going to be a true util function, I would compute the map outside of the function, and then reference it inside the util function, and export it. This way, it will only be computed once.

Comment: Thank you so much this was exactly what I was looking for. What exactly are you showing in the map though? the reduce function totals up the values of the letters but what does the i (index) value represent? I can't figure it out.

Comment: @ejbee3 It's to retain a reference to the original array, but I should just pass the word through rather than the index, I'll update my answer now :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
let testStr = 'man i need a taxi up to ubud'

const values = [...Array(27).keys()]
values.shift()
const keys = String.fromCharCode(...[...Array('z'.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1).keys()]
  .map(i => i + 'a'.charCodeAt(0)))
const merged = [...keys].reduce((obj, key, index) => ({ ...obj,
  [key]: values[index]
}), {})
console.log(JSON.stringify(merged) + '\n' + testStr)


const result = testStr.split(' ')
  .reduce((acc, cur) => [
    ...acc, 
    {
      name: cur,
      value: [...cur].reduce((sum, c) => sum + merged[c], 0)
    }
  ], [])
  .reduce((prev, current) => (prev.value > current.value) ? prev : current)
  .name;

console.log(result);
```